# How do we deploy a Pharo seaside web application?

Tags: cloud, smalltalk, pharo, seaside, pharo-5

I know there is a good explanation in the book Entreprise Pharo for deployment production over a Linux server. I followed the tutorial and was able to deploy the same project. However the project contained only a simple class 'MyFirstWebApp' and did not include Seaside framework. The run script was as followed:

`ZnServer defaultOn: 8080.
ZnServer default logToStandardOutput.
ZnServer default delegate
   map: 'image'
     to: MyFirstWebApp new;
   map: 'redirect-to-image'
     to: [ :request | ZnResponse redirect: 'image' ];
   map: '/'
     to: 'redirect-to-image'.
ZnServer default start`.

What about if you have a project with many classes using Seaside framework? I repeated the same procedure for my own Seaside project but I get a message error `WARequestContextNotFound` when I launch the run.st script with the following command `./pharo myapp.image run.st`. Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

You're mixing the use of pure Zinc Server delegates with the handling of Seaside Applications. Zinc provides a "server adaptor" for Seaside, that can be setup using `ZnZincServerAdaptor startOn: 8080` (or any port of your choice).

If you want to run a Seaside web application, you must deploy an image with the Seaside framework installed in it, along with your own classes (`MyFirstWebApp` and friends).

So your `run.st` would look more like:

```
ZnZincServerAdaptor  startOn: 8080.
ZnZincServerAdaptor default server debugMode: true.
ZnServer default logToStandardOutput.

"Here you register the Seaside application _class_"
(WAAdmin register: MyFirstWebApp asApplicationAt: 'image')
    preferenceAt: #serverPath put: '/'.
WAAdmin defaultDispatcher defaultName: 'image'.
```